# Wordpress site with embedded menu - gives You don't have permission to access /wp-content/themes/xxx/taxonomy-redirect.php on this server

Tags: php, taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic

I've inherited a website which has a menu structure that is not working.  he developer built a site at huge expense but has then left them with a partially working site. It is a WooCommerce site with a custom template. I cannot understand how this is supposed to work - any help much appreciated. :-)

The menu in question is:

```
 <form id="filter_dropdown_form" method="GET" action="http://www.punjaban.co.uk/wp-content/themes/punjaban/taxonomy-redirect.php">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
                                        <select name="term_filter" id="" class="turnintodropdown">
                                            <option value="">Product Categories</option>
 <option value="12">Accompaniments</option> <option value="20">Bread</option> <option value="9">Curry Bases</option> <option value="10">Pickles and Chutneys</option>                                        </select>
                                        <input type="submit" value="Filter" class="fallback" />
                                        <input type="hidden" name="taxonomy_name" value="product_cat" />
                                    </form>
```

None of the categories work, an error is displayed suggesting permissions to the taxonomy-redirect.php file aren't correct (it is 644).

Taxonomy-redirect.php:

```
<?php
require $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ] . '/wp-blog-header.php';

$term_id = $_GET[ 'term_filter' ];
$url = '';
if ( $term_id !== '' ) {
    $taxonomy_name = $_GET[ 'taxonomy_name' ];
    $url = get_term_link( intval( $term_id ), $taxonomy_name );
}
else {
    $post_type = $_GET[ 'post_type' ];
    $url = get_post_type_archive_link( $post_type );
}
//$url .= '#filter_anchor';
wp_redirect( $url, 301 );
```

There are 2 files called taxonomy-recipes-category.php and taxonomy-stockists-category.php . The code is below:

```
application/x-httpd-php taxonomy-recipes-category.php ( PHP script text )

<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying archive recipes.
 *
 * Learn more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package Punjaban
 */

get_header();
$post_type = 'recipes'
?>
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

<?php
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/slider' );
?>
            <div id="content-section" class="<?php echo $post_type; ?>-loop-wrap text-center">
                <div class="row">
                    <h2><?php the_field($post_type . '_listing_title', 'option'); ?></h2>
<?php
                    if ( have_posts( ) ) {
                        $recipes_categories = get_terms(
                            'recipes-category',
                            array(
                                'orderby'           => 'name',
                                'order'             => 'ASC',
                                'hide_empty'        => true,
                            )
                        );
                        $term_slug = get_query_var( 'recipes-category' );
                        if (count( $recipes_categories > 0 ) ){
?>
                            <form id="filter_dropdown_form" method="GET" action="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri( ); ?>/taxonomy-redirect.php">
                                <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="<?php echo $post_type; ?>" />
                                <select name="term_filter" id="" class="turnintodropdown">
                                    <option value="">View Recipes With</option>
<?php
                                    foreach( $recipes_categories as $recipes_category ) {
                                       echo ' <option value="' . $recipes_category->term_id . '"' . selected( $term_slug === $recipes_category->slug, true, false ) . '>' . $recipes_category->name . '</option>';
                                    }
?>
                                </select>
                                <input type="submit" value="Filter" class="fallback" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="taxonomy_name" value="recipes-category" />
                            </form>
<?php
                        }
?>
                        <section id="isotope-container" class="isotope-wrap text-center">
<?php
                            $current_page = get_query_var( 'paged' );
                            if ( !$current_page ) {
                                $current_page = 1;
                            }

                            $featured = get_field( 'featured_recipe_of_the_month', 'options' );
                            if ( !empty( $featured ) && $current_page == 1 ) {
                                get_template_part( 'listing-feat-' . $post_type, '' );
                            }

                            while ( have_posts() ) {
                                the_post();
                                get_template_part( 'listing', $post_type );
                            }
?>
                            <span class="clearboth"></span>
                        </section>
<?php
                    }
                    else {
                        //get_template_part('content', 'none');
                        echo '<p>Sorry, no products here</p>';
                    }
?>
                </div>
<?php
                if ( have_posts( ) ) {
                    global $wp_query;
                    echo TC_Library::get_paging( $wp_query->found_posts, $wp_query->query_vars[ 'posts_per_page' ], array( ) );
                }
?>
            </div>
<?php
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/cta' );
?>
        </main>
    </div>
<?php
get_footer();
```

Am I correct in thinking that you would need a file per pag? For example they have the same category dropdown on the Blog and Woocommerce shop page but I cannot see any code relating to that.

The website is [www.punjaban.co.uk](http://www.punjaban.co.uk) Thank you.

Comment: Hi Helen, welcome to WPSE. Unfortunately there's not enough here to figure out what you're asking (there isn't even any PHP code), and we can't rewrite the entire menu for you from scratch. It sounds like you need a developer to be honest.

Comment: Hi Tim,  thanks for your comment, I appreciate there's not much to go on.  I'll add the php code, not that I;m expecting you to rewrite anything, I just need to understand if there is a bug or whether it was never completed in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, when I looked at the .htaccess file it had the following:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:php)$">
  <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

I removed that and the menu works correctly. This may open up risks to other files so I will post on the Linux page to clarify the correction. Thanks Gary for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Hi Helen, glad you solved the problem. Please use the check mark to the left of this answer to mark it as the solution (yes, you can do that for self-answers :) ), so that this question doesn't come up in our unanswered list. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The server is setup correctly, no one should be able to execute php which is not at the root directory of wordpress (if he cares about the site's security). You can look into the htaccess or other server settings to figure out how it was done and remove it, but -10 for that option.

The form and its server side handling do not make any sense at all. Either replace the form with links to the actual term pages, or use some JS to direct to them

Answer (score 0):

From the explanation you have posted it sounds like your webserver does not have permission to execute the PHP script. If the Webserver is Linux, you can use CHMOD and CHOWN commands to modify the persmissons and change the owner respectively, but if you are not familiar with linux, you are best asking your hosting support to help with this.

You would need to ensure the webserver account on the server is the 'owner' of the directory the file resides in, and that it has permission to execute the script. `CHMOD 744` for example would give the web server (providing the webserver is the owner of the file and directory) permission to execute the file and everyone permission to read. Definately sounds like a permissions issue on the webserver. You can also check the webserver error log which might give you some more information if you have access to the server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gary, the permissions were 0644. I changed to 0744 but the same thing happens.

Comment: Hi Helen sorry to hear. Nice work on adding more information to your question. I've found this post [here](https://themeforest.net/forums/thread/wordpress-custom-taxonomy-help-404-page-not-found/76735) which may be of some help to you.

Comment: Hi Gary, I'd not checked the error log but having just done so it is full of errors:[Wed Jul 27 08:37:44 2016] [error] [client 82.19.13.185] client denied by server configuration: /home/punjaban/public_html/wp-content/themes/punjaban/taxonomy-redirect.php       Tried saving the permalinks but to no avail.

Comment: If the server was setup correctly you would not be getting "[Wed Jul 27 08:37:44 2016] [error] [client 82.19.13.185] client denied by server configuration: /home/punjaban/public_html/wp-content/themes/punjaban/taxonomy-redirect.php" Apache error codes. Of course 'someone' should be able to execute PHP, namely the webserver. Frightening that people post answers without even reading the full scope of the question, suggested solutions, and comments. Definately worth asking the question in linux, or stack overflow I would suggest, good luck.